# Putting a message in an inbox (Django models)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a couple of models and am a little confused about how to create all of the associations. I have profiles, events, messages, and inboxes. Each profile has an eventList that holds events. Each message is associated with an event too. Each inbox is associated with a profile and multiple messages. What I want to do is, whenever a message object is created, for it to be inserted into the inbox of every user who holds the event that message is associated with in their eventList. Providing my models and the view that I'm writing:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='event_set+')
    ownedEvent = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='owned_set')
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

class inbox(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.name
    user = models.OneToOneField(Profile)
    message = models.ManyToManyField(message, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE")
    read = models.BooleanField(default = 0)

class message(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.body)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.today()
        super(message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    eid = models.ForeignKey(Event)


@login_required
def sendMail(request):

    event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    e = Event.objects.get(id = event_id)
    text = request.POST['body']

    m = message(eid = e, body = text)
    m.save()

    users = e.eventList_set.all()

    return HttpResponse(status = 200)
```

Comment: If you want to be consistent with Python / Django coding style, you might consider: 1) Capitalizing class names (e.g. `Inbox`) 2) Using lowercase and underscores for function and attribute names (e.g. `send_mail`, `event_list`) 3) Using plural names for M2M fields (e.g. `messages`, `owned_events`). It's up to you, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to always happen you can put the relevant code in the `message.save()` method or a post-save signal handler. If it's just for this view then you can put the code there. In either case, this should work:

```
# msg is the message instance
for box in inbox.objects.filter(user__eventList=msg.eid):
    box.message.add(msg)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Remember, `msg` is just a name I made up, the actual name of the message instance depends on where you put this code. If it's in `message.save()` you should use `self`, if it's in the view as given above, you should use `m`.